# optimize code to increment char value

Tags: c#, optimization, ascii

Here is my c# code to increment the ascii value by 13

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32('z');
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            {
                if (a > 96 && a < 122)
                {
                    a++;
                }
                else
                {
                    a = 97;
                }

            }
            string c = Convert.ToChar(a).ToString();
```

So this outputs `m` which is `z+13`
Any way to avoid the for loop.

Basically i'm trying to implement [ROT-13](http://www.dotnetperls.com/rot13)

Comment: have you tried a+=13 ?

Comment: @dada686 well i guess i missed some parts of code.have a look

Comment: **this outputs `n`**... hmm, I don't think it outputs anything. You're just assigning.

Comment: its inside a for loop

Comment: +1 for the question evolution :)

Answer (score 2):

### Initial answer

You could of course just do `a += 13;` where you now do the for loop.

But this can be shortened further.

```
char c = 'a';
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
    c = (char)(((int)c)+13);
}
```

### Update

With your updated question I think you can do it with the following:

```
char c = 'z';
c = (char)(((int)'a') + ((c - (int)'a' + 13) % 26));
// Output c = 'm'
// If you use c = 'a', then the output is c = 'n'
```

And actually you can remove the casts to int, and some parenthesis. Which leaves the following, which might be a little clearer.

```
char c = 'z';
c = (char)('a' + (c - 'a' + 13) % 26);
// Output c = 'm'
// If you use c = 'a', then the output is c = 'n'
```

Comment: This is indeed shortened but I don't think it is easier to read.

Comment: @dada686 Easier to read then what, my initial answer? My updated answer is giving the correct answer (I think) to the updated question, that's a start :-)

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the updated version.

Comment: @dada686 I've removed some bits which might make it a little clearer.

Comment: This will fail for, let's say, `.`;

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
a += 13;
```

Now if after this addition the number is too high, you should be able to subtract 26 to "wrap around".

Comment: Damn, you found a way past the error quicker than I did :p

Comment: It's idiotic, really. Just like the "Trivial answer converted to comment".

Comment: update code have a look

Comment: @iBlue you might want to explain the problem a little better. So you don't want to always add 13, you want to implement [ROT-13](http://www.dotnetperls.com/rot13). Explain what you are doing, what the expected result is, what actually happens and how you have tried to solve that difference.

Comment: this won't wrap around for `z`, you'll need some sort of modulo as in @Maarten's anwser.

Comment: @tehlexx thank you, but that was not in the original question and I'm not going to implement ROT-13 for OP since I guess this is homework.

Comment: @CodeCaster If you're not going to edit it, I think you should delete it, since this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @OscarMederos yes, let's keep the quality high.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `for` loop - you can just simply add 13 to the `int` value:

```
a = a + 13;
```

or

```
a += 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this for loop :

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32('z');
            if (a > 96 && a < 122)
            {
                a+=13;
            }
            else
            {
                a = 97;
            }
        string c = Convert.ToChar(a).ToString();
```

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Yes, Why ?

Comment: @dada686 if input is z i need m as output.simple adding 13 to ascii of z wont give u m.I hope i'm clear

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32('z');
a = (a >= 97 && a <= 122) ?
        (a > 109) ?
            a -= 13 : a += 13 : (a >= 65 && a <= 90) ?
                (a > 77) ?
                    a -= 13 : a += 13 : a;
string c = Convert.ToChar(a).ToString();
```

It's basically the [C# ROT13 Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/rot13) for a single character, but in a shorter (and less readable) form.